# How to schedule a task to run while phone is charging?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making an app that needs to schedule a task to execute ONLY when the device is charging. I'm also making an Android versión of this same app. On Android I registered a BroadcastReceiver which listens for the ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED intent. 
So, my question is:
How can I accomplish the same thing on Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: You may take a look at [Maintenance trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ883699(v=win.10).aspx) - it's fired once the phone is connected to external power.

Comment: I'm going to try it. It seems to be what I have been looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8 apps you can create background agents as ResourceIntensiveTasks. These tasks runs only when phone is charging. More about it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx